# Differentiating a definite integral

Tags: integration, matrices, derivatives

I am unsure of how to differentiate the follow expression:

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int_\tau^t \Phi(t,\alpha)\cdot A(\alpha)\cdot x(\alpha) d\alpha
$$

where $\Phi(t,\alpha)$ and $A(\alpha)$ are matrices.

Comment: Formally, you just interchange differentiation and integration. To justify the interchange, use Leibniz' rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about $\Phi$ and $A$ (and $x$ too), nothing much can be said, but [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) might help:

$$\frac{\operatorname d \;}{\operatorname d t}\int_c^t \Phi(t,\alpha)\cdot A(\alpha)\cdot x(\alpha)\operatorname d \alpha \;=\; \int_c^t \frac{\partial\; \Phi(t,\alpha)}{\partial\; t}\cdot A(\alpha)\cdot x(\alpha)\operatorname d \alpha + \Phi(t,t)\cdot A(t)\cdot x(t)$$

Comment: For the second term, did you mean $\Phi(t,t)\cdot A(t)\cdot x(t)$?

Comment: Yes, @truhoang .  Thank you.